# Unity3D problems building on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, build

I'm trying to "build" a game project made on Unity3D, but keep getting errors unrelated to the code; as far as I understand.

- Unity 3D version 2018.3.0f2
- MacBook Pro, MacOS Mojave v. 10.14.2

The game runs fine on this and two other devices which run a Windows 10 OS. It builds without problems on the Windows OS, but not on the MacOS.
The project is the exact same; copied via flash-drive to transfer between the two, and pulled as a git project.

I have tried installing Unity3D via the install assistant, and via Unity Hub; neither made a difference.

I made sure all required dependencies were installed, and re-installed multiple times. Clean installs, restarts, even the OS was re-installed as I had literally just gotten this laptop to work on my Unity game-dev projects.
After many failed attempts, I made a partitioned drive specifically for this project, re installed everything and ran the project for the firs time. Test played it, it ran well, but still wouldn't build. I did that because I thought it was a security or "access rights" problem.
With that, I even allowed Unity access to the whole drive via the security settings of the Mac OS.

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqbwh.jpg "Error Screenshot".

What was expected was that the project would build without problems; what happened was that I got these errors which I will try to post a picture of.

- The error in text in-case screenshot doesn't work:
- [1]

  > UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Volumes/(edited >out)/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Unity.Analytics.StandardEvents.dll" >is denied.
  >   System.IO.File.Delete (System.String path) (at :0)
  >   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyStripper (System.Collections.IEnumerable assemblies, System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, System.String[] assembliesToStrip, System.String[] searchDirs, System.String monoLinkerPath, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:372)
  >   UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssemblies (System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:216)
  >   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:203)
  >   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:42)
  >   DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] filesToNotOverwrite) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:245)
  >   DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:46)
  >   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
- [2]

  > UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  >   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  >   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96 
  >   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Try deleting the Temp and Library folder in your Unity Project, then rebuild it.

Comment: @JeanLuc Thanks for the comment, but that didn't work either.
I had suspected that it may have been the issue; but the error I posted happened after having deleted the temp folder.

Note: I tried a fresh build after pulling the project from git, and I tried a re-build after deleting that folder and restarting Unity. Both cases, same issue.

Comment: I went through reading a bunch of other help tips; messed with terminal, user rights, root access, and nothing worked. 

I even completely formatted my drive, installed a fresh new copy of Mojave (Mac OS), installed Unity again, created a fresh new project with nothing in the scene but a cube. 
I ran that, built, and that worked.

Then pulled my project from git, ran it, and same errors.
This project runs and builds on other systems, but not my Mac OS.
Could it be that it was initially coded and setup via Windows OS?
Does that matter at all?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has problems building their Unity3D project on a Mac, I may have found a solution for my problem that could help others.

Two things, one of which may have been the cause of it.

1) I basically ran the Packages Manager within Unity, and removed all packages that were initially added via the Windows version of Unity3D (for Android). I don't know much about this part, but that worked.

2) You need to download and install the latest Xcode from the AppStore, run it with template project (something to make it run and start up); that way it downloads any dependencies or required files. Then, close project, restart the computer, and once back; run your Unity3D project and try building again.

That basically fixed it for me, as there were certain files in the project that needed some "access rights" that were not possible without Xcode being there and installed; which, I think, allows those things to happen.

I hope that helps others.
Best of luck.